# Is there a way to print html using blutooth thermal printer -flutter?

Tags: flutter, arabic, thermal-printer

I am building an app using flutter, and I want to print Arabic texts through a Bluetooth thermal printer. I figured if I wrote HTML, it would be easier, but I couldn't find a package that could help me with the issue.
Any suggestions?
Thank you.